# Swift - adding clear button to UITextfield programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uitextfield

I am having problems adding a clear button to my `UITextfield`.

This is my `textfield`:

```
let emailTextField: CustomTextField = {
    let v = CustomTextField()
    v.borderActiveColor = .white
    v.borderInactiveColor = .white
    v.textColor = .white
    v.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Regular", size: 17)
    v.placeholder = "Email-Adresse"
    v.placeholderColor = .gray
    v.placeholderFontScale = 1
    v.clearButtonMode = UITextField.ViewMode.always
    v.minimumFontSize = 13
    v.borderStyle = .line
    v.autocapitalizationType = .none
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return v
}()
```

As you can see I set `clearButtonMode = .always` but it is not being displayed.

My `CustomTextFieldClass` is nothing special either:

```
class CustomTextField: HoshiTextField {

    /// the left padding
    @IBInspectable public var leftPadding: CGFloat = 0 { didSet { self.setNeedsLayout() } }

    /// the right padding
    @IBInspectable public var rightPadding: CGFloat = 0 { didSet { self.setNeedsLayout() } }

    /// Text rectangle
    ///
    /// - Parameter bounds: the bounds
    /// - Returns: the rectangle
    override public func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        let originalRect: CGRect = super.editingRect(forBounds: bounds)
        return CGRect(x: originalRect.origin.x + leftPadding, y: originalRect.origin.y, width: originalRect.size.width - leftPadding - rightPadding, height: originalRect.size.height)
    }

    /// Editing rectangle
    ///
    /// - Parameter bounds: the bounds
    /// - Returns: the rectangle
    override public func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        let originalRect: CGRect = super.editingRect(forBounds: bounds)
        return CGRect(x: originalRect.origin.x + leftPadding, y: originalRect.origin.y, width: originalRect.size.width - leftPadding - rightPadding, height: originalRect.size.height)
    }
```

Does anyone know why the clear button is not being displayed???

Comment: When do you want to display it? Can you see it after filling a text into the text field?

Comment: nope. I want want to always display it.

Comment: Just for testing purposes, can you make your text field a `UITextField` and see if it shows up?

Comment: ... it is being displayed. but why????

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue since I have no idea what `HoshiTextField ` is...

Comment: https://github.com/raulriera/TextFieldEffects  Its from this git repo

Comment: I used the provided `CustomTextField` and it works fine! It seems the issue is somewhere else...

Comment: aaaah. That makes no sense

Comment: https://github.com/DieGlueckswurst/Wishlist This is my project. At the moment I am trying to change everything to programmatically. The clearButton was visible before but now it is not.. If you want to have a look, I am working on "LoginVC.swift"  at the moment.

Comment: @Chris if it works fine with just a `UITextField` the problem must be in `CustomTextField` or `HoshiTextField`.

Comment: Looking at `HoshiTextField` you can see the issue in  `drawViewsForRect` - it does it's own drawing. Please file a bug report with that project.

Comment: yep, already did that.